# @Output from Child component doesn't trigger EventEmitter in Angular 5

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I'm trying to use @Output with the event emitter to communicate between child to parent component to pass a variable. I followed this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular

I have taken a look to different stackoverflow questions related to this, but none work for my case.

**Child HTML**

```
<button (click)="onLinkedClicked();">Click me</button>
```

**Child TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
.
.
.
export class showcaseMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() public linkedClicked = new EventEmitter<String>();

    constructor() {}

    onLinkedClicked() {
        console.log('on click child');
        this.linkedClicked.emit('collapsed');
    }
}
```

It prints the log 'on click child'

**Parent HTML**

```
 <showcase-menu #topNavMenu [showBranding]="false"
     [showSearch]= "false" (onLinkedClicked)="linkToggler($event)"></showcase-menu>
```

**Parent TS**

```
.
.
.
 navMenuState: string;
.
.
.
  linkToggler($event) {
    console.log("partent");
    this.navMenuState = $event;
  }
```

The linkToggler() never gets called. And I don't have any error in the console,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event must match the name of the property associated with the Output decorator

```
<showcase-menu #topNavMenu 
               [showBranding]="false"
               [showSearch]= "false"  
               (linkedClicked)="linkToggler($event)">. 
</showcase-menu>
```